My 20 amp breaker trips
I just had my shop wired all outlet’s are 20 amp 12 gauge wire. There are 5 outlets per 20 amp breaker. Problem I have been dealing with, when I go to the shop and first time I start my mitre saw it trips the breaker, after I reset the breaker I can go use the mitre saw no tripping the breaker. If I stop using the saw for a little while and go back to it sometimes trips the breaker again. The saw is a model dsw779 15 amp saw. Nothing else is running in that breaker at the time the saw trips it. I have also have a skill saw trip a breaker at one of the other stations , and my planer. I am confused on what the problem could be, never had this happen in my other shop that was wired for all 20 amp breakers.

Are they the same tools you used in the previous shop?

start up or rush current can do that

Have you swapped the breaker out? Sometimes they pop at lower than rated.

@Traveler The specified mitre saw (actually DWS779 not DSW) uses a universal motor with no starting capacitors. The skill saw (likely Skil ) also likely has a universal motor, based on Skil's website of available models (though a model number for OP's saw could clear up the matter further).

Kelly, are your circuit breakers AFCI? Or are they regular overcurrent-only breakers? And what kind of breakers were in the old shop? Thought: AFCI might trigger on the sparking brushes typical of a universal motor, such as your DWS779 saw has.

Is this shop a long distance from the main panel? What is the distance from the main panel to the shop panel, and what gauge wire was used? (Specify Cu or Al.)
It's possible that if your supply wire gauge to the shop's subpanel is inadequate, you are getting a deep voltage slump when starting a motor. The starting amps for a 15 amp motor may be 45 amps or more. If you get a voltage slump, the motor struggles to start, and the high current condition is prolonged while the motor comes up to speed.
Breakers don't pop immediately when the current exceeds the breaker rating. They allow a brief overcurrent to accommodate motor starts and other momentary conditions. You appear to be right on the edge of the time x current curve that trips the breaker.
As an example, a Square D QO breaker rated for 20 amps will trip instantaneously at 120 amps. A 90 amp load will trip it in 1 second. A 40 amp load will trip it in 8 seconds. The full graph is available here. Note that different brands of breakers have different time x current trip characteristics.
Suggest you measure voltage at the outlet while starting the saw to see if you have a severe momentary voltage drop. This brief drop can't be measured with a standard digital voltmeter; you need one with a min/max setting, or you can use an old-school analog voltmeter with a fast needle.
If you don't presently have equipment to measure a brief voltage drop, you can get at least some idea (without numbers) by plugging in a lamp with an incandescent bulb (not LED, not CFL) to the same outlet as the saw. If you see noticeable dimming that lasts longer than the blink of an eye, you should follow up with a voltage measurememt.
If you learn that your supply wiring is inadequate, you could run heavier wire but a less expensive option is to add a soft-start accessory to any equipment that frequently pops the breaker when starting.

This doesn't seem to explain why the breaker doesn't trip on subsequent starts: the thermal element should be warmed by the first trip, so if anything, subsequent starts should be more likely to trip.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica True enough. But the saw also warms up in use. The grease gets thinner for less turning resistance. The motor windings heat up, raising motor resistance. The motor laminations get hot, reducing magnetic permeability and therefore motor current. I found one spec for a motor studied in a white paper on temperature effects on motors where locked rotor current at 25C was 40.7A but at 125C was 28.9A. A mitre saw won't get that hot, but still, the effect is real.

Ooh, yeah. Hadn't considered effects of a warm motor. Interesting.
